# VLOOKUP for multiple entries

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have a few columns in a sheet. First column being first names and the fifth being their respective age. If I want to search the age column for a particular age say '12' and return their corresponding first names in a separate sheet, what should i do? I tried VLOOKUP but I could not figure out the logic. Can someone help me out?Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `VLOOKUP` will not work in this situation,as the Vlookup function cannot reference details on left side, however  you can use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions thou. Lets say you have following table

```
A              B
mark          11
john          23
Selly         30
Youbaraj      45
```

and you want to get the value of `A` based on the value of `B`, you can use something like

```
=INDEX(A1:A20,MATCH(1,B1:B20,0))
```

You can use index and match to do `HLOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP` looking into any column and getting values of any side.

You can use an Index and Double match .. to get answers from a column by entering its name.

Example:

```
    A      B      C      D  
   1 col1   col2   col3   col4  
   2 val1   val2   val3   val4
   3 val5   val6   val7   val8
```

Consider in cell `C10` ColumnName: 
And in cell `C11`, you enter the name of a column

Now see what would happen with this function

```
 =index(A1:D3,Match(C11,A1:D1,0),Match(val-to-look-for, Column (a,b,c,d),0))
```

You can dynamically type a name of a column to get that column name's look up value

Comment: Mark the question as answered please

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup is very easy to use, however the first column must be arranged alphabeticaly before in order for it to work properly. (and usualy i use only the exact match argument).